# Primes in Quadratic Fields with Norm less than 6

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, field-theory

What are the primes in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{−1}]$ which have norm less than $6$? Also what primes in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{−3}]$ have norm less than $6$, and the primes in $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{−5}]$? Which of them are associates of each other? Can we prove that the numbers found are prime and that there are no others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if $\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathcal O$ is a prime ideal in the ring of integers of any number field $K/\mathbb{Q}$, then it lies over some rational prime $p\in \mathbb Z$, and the norm of $\mathfrak{p}$ will be a power of $p$.

So in any case, the only possibilities are primes that divide $2,\: 3, $ or $5$. Check those cases for your 3 number fields.

For example in $K = \mathbb{Q}[i]$, then $(1-i )|2$, with norm $N(1-i) =2$, and this is the only prime lying over $2$.

The ideal $(3)$ is prime in $K$, and has norm $N(3) = 9>6$, so that doesn't work.

And finally, the ideal $(5)$ splits with $(2+i)$ and $(3+i)$ lying over it, both ideals having norm $5$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not used to some of the terminology that you used. Such as: $\mathfrak{p} \subset \mathcal O$. If you can, can you elaborate some more on your answer. I would appreciate it. Thank You

Comment: Well, in number fields, we don't talk about prime elements as much as prime ideals. It is a theorem that, even though we might not have unique factorization into prime elements, there is unique factorization of ideals into prime ideals.

Comment: when I say $\mathfrak{p}$ lies over a prime number $p\in \mathbb{Z}$, what I mean is that $\mathfrak{p}|(p)$ as ideals. Equivalently, $p\in \mathfrak{p}$.